# Postgres pg_dump cache lookup failed for index

Tags: postgresql, runtime-error

I am trying to create a back-up of a postgres database using the following command (omitting details):

```
$ pg_dump -h $host -p 5432 -U $user $db > db.sql
```

After some time, I get an error (formatted)

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  cache lookup failed for index 1184605879
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: 
SELECT  t.tableoid, 
        t.oid, 
        t.relname AS indexname, 
        pg_catalog.pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid) AS indexdef, 
        t.relnatts AS indnkeys, 
        i.indkey, 
        i.indisclustered, 
        false AS indisreplident, 
        t.relpages, 
        c.contype, 
        c.conname, 
        c.condeferrable, 
        c.condeferred, 
        c.tableoid AS contableoid, 
        c.oid AS conoid, 
        pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid, false) AS condef, 
        (SELECT spcname FROM pg_catalog.pg_tablespace s WHERE s.oid = t.reltablespace) AS tablespace, 
        t.reloptions AS indreloptions 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_index i 
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class t ON (t.oid = i.indexrelid) 
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint c ON (i.indrelid = c.conrelid AND i.indexrelid = c.conindid AND c.contype IN ('p','u','x')) 
WHERE i.indrelid = '1184605870'::pg_catalog.oid AND i.indisvalid AND i.indisready 
ORDER BY indexname
```

I then verified the index ID in `pg_index` does not exist. Is there some way to fix this, or some way to ignore this error and continue so I can continue exporting non-`pg_catalog` data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a quick script that dumped each table individually to a sql file and found that it was some temporary login information that was causing the cache to fail. I simply excluded that table from the export and it was fine.

I'm not the best bash programmer so it can definitely be improved, but here is the script I used to dump each table individually to find which table was causing the error.

```
#!/bin/bash
host=$1
port=$2
user=$3
db=$4

# Get all table names that you will be dumping individually
query="SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE tableowner=$user;"
tables=( $(psql -h $host -p $port -U $user $d -c $query) )
mkdir db_dump

dump_command="pg_dump -h $host -p $port -U $user"
for table in $(tables[@]); do
    eval "$dump_command -t $table $db > db_dump/$table.sql"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that a system index get corrupted. I'd try the following:

1. Stop database server
2. Start database in single-user mode, ignoring system and user-defined indexes:

   `postgres --single -D /path/to/data --ignore_system_indexes=on --enable_indexscan=off --enable_bitmapscan=off <database>`
3. Reindex entire database (including catalog): `REINDEX DATABASE
   <database>;`
4. Restart database and try dumping again...

More: [ignore_system_indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-developer.html), [REINDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reindex.html), [enable_bitmapscan/enable_indexscan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html), [single-user mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html#APP-POSTGRES-SINGLE-USER);

Comment: I tried this and still get an error with a different index value. There are other systems using this database so I will get back to you after making sure none of the other systems are automatically re-connecting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your database is corrupted, and you should restore from a backup.

If are not afraid of messing with the catalogs (make a physical backup first!):

Set the configuration parameter `allow_system_table_mods` to `on` so you can modify system catalogs. Then

```
DELETE FROM pg_catalog.pg_index WHERE indexrelid = 1184605879;
```

Maybe that gets your database in a state where you can dump it (minus that index).

If there are more problems, you might end up extracting table data one by one with `COPY` and see what else you can salvage.

Comment: I re-tested the dump a couple more times this morning (without changing anything) and each time it comes out with a different index number. I think there may be a different underlying problem. I will try to extract each table one by one to see which table is causing problems.

Comment: Sounds like the whole `pg_index` syste catalog is corrupted. Or maybe only the index `pg_index_indrelid_index` is broken, and reindexing `pg_index` fixes the problem.