# Fixing corrupt table

Tags: postgresql, corruption

I was trying to upgrade Sentry and a table in my database got corrupt.
After reading about vacuum and reindex I was able to track down the issue to a single table.

Doing a `select *` from any other table works just fine, but this particular one seems to be problematic. Is there a way I can fix the table, or, worst case scenario, dump all other tables somehow?

`pg_dump -T corrupt_table > bkp.sql` doesn't work:

```
bash-4.4# pg_dump -U XXXXXX -T sentry_identityprovider sentry > bkp.sql
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  cache lookup failed for attribute 1 of relation 45941
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT tableoid, oid, conname, confrelid, pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(oid) AS condef FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint WHERE conrelid = '45954'::pg_catalog.oid AND contype = 'f'
```

Please avoid comments like "Well, go get your backups". I'm asking because I don't have a backup.

Also, please avoid comments like "Well, if you don't have backups, shit happens". I'm asking because there was an error in the execution of the backups and none were made.

Also, please avoid any other helpless comments related to backups. Really. You're not helping me that way.

Comment: Have you tried starting the database in single user mode and re-indexing your table(s) [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47705855/9973881)? Depending on how badly the database is corrupted this might get you a bit further.

Comment: perhaps you can drop the damaged table `drop tablename cascade;` (this will also drop constraints that involve it) after dropping you should be able to do a backup.

Comment: If you are asking for help on a public forum, you'll have to be able to deal with some comments about missing backups for important data. What is the result of the following: `SELECT * FROM pg_attribute WHERE attrelid = 45941 ORDER BY attnum;`.

Answer (score 0):

At some stage I have been able to dump and restore an individual table as per below. Note in help for pg_dump that you should be able to do a full dump and exclude the corrupt table, never tried it. Not sure why yours fails, dumping a single good table might give the answer. Hope it works for you.

```
pg_dump -t good_table old_DB -U youruser -f good_table_BUP.sql  

psql -f good_table_BUP.sql  new_DB

 -t, --table=TABLE            dump the named table(s) only
 -T, --exclude-table=TABLE    do NOT dump the named table(s)
```

Comment: Also on the problem table try ALTER TABLE xx DROP CONSTRAINT xxname and drop any indexes, drop everything other than the table